# I'm unable to check that a checkbox is changed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a checkbox using the following code

```
<CheckBox Color="Red" CheckedChanged="{Binding OnCheckBoxCheckChanged}" >
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Color"
                            Value="Red" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="IsChecked">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Color"
                            Value="Green" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </CheckBox>
```

I have then created the following OnCheckBoxCheckChanged function that is being binded to on the checkbox (this is currently located in the view model.cs file):

```
void OnCheckBoxCheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Value.Equals(true))
            {
                VanData.PPECheck = true;
                _PPECheck = true;            }
            else
            {
                VanData.PPECheck = false;
                _PPECheck = false;
            }
        }
```

**The error here is** that in my Visual Studio editor when trying to bind when creating the checkbox it says "No DataContext" and when looking at my function it says there is no references. I am using a standard Xamarin.Forms template (Tabbed View) and this is currently in the "AddNewItem" page. The .xaml code is located in the .xaml file obviously. The function I have attempted this in both AddNewItem view model, the .cs file attached to the AddNewItem.xaml file. I am fairly new to Xaml so unsure of the issue, but I believe that the binding can't find my function?

Any help appreciated and if any more info is needed let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you only `bind` **commands** - event handlers are assigned like `CheckedChanged="OnCheckBoxCheckChanged"`

Comment: Sorry I had forgot to mention I had tried this, this is the error I receive when changing to this: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error XFC0002 EventHandler "OnCheckBoxCheckChanged" with correct signature not found in type "CadentPPE1CheckApp.Views.NewItemPage". CadentPPE1CheckApp C:\Users\haydn\source\repos\CadentPPE1CheckApp\CadentPPE1CheckApp\CadentPPE1CheckApp\Views\Internals\NewItemPage.xaml 16

Comment: event handlers belong in the code behind, not the VM

Comment: I get you, but how do I then relate this to the checkbox? Ive put the function in the NewItemPage.cs, but then when im creating the checkbox in the NewItemPage.xaml, how do I then call upon this function?

Comment: I'm with you, God knows what I was thinking, peeked definition and it was empty, all sorted, thanks for your help, true MVP!

Comment: It sounds like you may have solved this, but for future reference, you can [turn an event into a command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior) that you can hook up to your VM

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code in a MVVM way, you could try EventToCommandBehavior as
Andrew mentioned in the comment.

First, we should install [Xamarin Community Toolkit Nuget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/).

Then in xaml file, we add the Behaviors to CheckBox. EventToCommandBehavior change the **CheckedChanged** event to **CheckValueCommand** (we will define it later in viewmodel). It also pass IsChecked property value as parameter  to **CheckValueCommand**.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         ......
         xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit">

<CheckBox Color="Red" x:Name="myCheck">
       <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
           ......
       </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   <CheckBox.Behaviors>
       <xct:EventToCommandBehavior
                   EventName="CheckedChanged"
                   CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference myCheck},Path=IsChecked}"
                   Command="{Binding CheckValueCommand}"/>
   </CheckBox.Behaviors>
```

In viewModel file, we define the CheckValueCommand:

```
    public Command CheckValueCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<bool>((e) =>
            {
                if (e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("true");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("false");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

For more info, you could refer to [Xamarin Community Toolkit EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior)

Hope it works.